# Trigger function when user print two and more letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `textbox`:

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text">
```

And this function:

```
function search(prefixText){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../Search/Address.aspx/GetCompletionList",
    data: "{ prefixText: prefixText, count: 10 }", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {
      alert("Done!")
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("error")
    }
  });
}
```

I need the function to be executed when ever `user enter two and more letters`.

How can I implement it using `JavaScript` or `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtSearch").on("keyup",function(){
   if($(this).val().length>=2)
       search($(this).val())
}):


function search(prefixText){

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../Search/Address.aspx/GetCompletionList",
                data: "{ prefixText: prefixText, count: 10 }", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (data) {
                  alert("Done!")
                },
                error: function (error) {
                  alert("error")
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     function search(prefixText){
         if(prefixText.length >=2)
       {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../Search/Address.aspx/GetCompletionList",
            data: "{ prefixText: prefixText, count: 10 }", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function (data) {
              alert("Done!")
            },
            error: function (error) {
              alert("error")
            }
        });
        }
        }
```

Is that what you want ?